# how to mysql select using where not found

Tags: php, mysql

let say we've two tables as following

Table `Users`

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id | username | email |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 | user1    | mail1 |
|  2 | user2    | mail2 |
|  3 | user3    | mail3 |
|  4 | user4    | mail4 |
+----+----------+-------+
```

Table `sales`

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id | username | email |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 | user1    | mail1 |
|  2 | user3    | mail3 |
+----+----------+-------+
```

I wanna print the emails of `users` where their username not found at `sales` table as if I wanna say select email from `users` where `username` not found in table `sales`

Output should be like this

```
email2
email4
```

Please note that i'm usring mysql  ~ thanks

Comment: I wish people would use "want to" rather than wanna ....

Comment: i was looking for using `LEFT JOIN` how could be on this example

Comment: @webnoob I totally agree, but what I would rather see is: "this is what I have tried and I am stuck with this specific part of the code, because X" instead of "here are my requirements gimme gimme gimme".

Comment: @PeeHaa webnoob will say now "i wish people would use give me rather than gimme " :)

Comment: @JackBen Lol :) I agree PeeHaa, you had that side covered though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many possible solutions on this problem. One is by using `LEFT JOIN`. Any record that has no matching record on the *right hand side* (`Sales`) table will have a value of `null` on its columns which you can filter with.

```
SELECT  a.email
FROM    Users a
        LEFT JOIN Sales b
            ON a.username = b.username
WHERE   b.username IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d9c2/1)

Comment: Thanks, works perfect and i did not understood very well how LEFT JOIN works .. also thanks for the SQLFiddel never knew it before .. this is awesome for testing and reviewing.

Answer (score 1):

```
select users.* from users left join sales on sales.username = users.username
where sales.username is null
```